# oracle sqlloader new line at the end of the file

Tags: oracle, plsql, sql-loader

have a file that is in format x,y which should be loaded using sql loader

x y
 a b
new line

All data is loaded to table A(x,y) where x,y are varchar2 - this step passes successfully.
Next step is processing loaded data - i.e. transforming data to proper formats etc.
At this step i get into trouble, since column y is converted to number (it stores numbers). However due to new line at the end of the file, this line gets corrupted and to_number conversion fails.

How could this be solved?

Comment: the error reason is end of file has only 0A while it would have regularly 0D0A. Though this is just encoding error, how can it be noticed/treated in other similar cases?

Comment: It sounds like you are creating the csv file on Unix and running Sql Loader on Windows.  Since the file is being created on Unix, why not use a conversion program like unix2dos to convert to the windows format (\r\n in lieu of \n).  Here is an example, http://superuser.com/questions/71507/convert-unix-line-endings-to-windows.

Answer (score 0):

- Contact the provider of the data and have them correct the process that creates the file.
- Use the LOAD= parameter to SQL*Loader to restrict how many lines to load LOAD=(lines in file - 1).
- Pre-process the file by stripping blank lines or removing special characters before loading.